PowerShell Assistance with Firewall Log Files
I'm hoping someone can help, there's a blog I've been working with https://www.imab.dk/getting-windows-11-cis-compliant-configuring-windows-firewall-logging-using-powershell-and-microsoft-intune/?unapproved=13092&moderation-hash=de9e980b1c37d462e5d63261b6ed1ba2#comment-13092
Basically, it advises how to check the Windows Firewall log files exists, if not , it'll apply the neccessary permissions to the Firewall log folder and the log size using Intune Remediations. I've got this in place and works nicely however, what I'd like to do is transfer this method into a Win32 App deployment. To do this, I need to essentially combine the scripts so that it'll perform the same checks to see if the log files exist and if they don't, to create them.
So for example the first two scripts to check whether the log folders exist with the appropriate permissions are below. I need to firstly combine these two:
Detection Script:
> <#
#.SYNOPSIS
#    This script detects if the log files for each firewall profile; domain, private and public exist with the correct permissions
#    If the files do not exist or do not have the correct permissions, the script will exit with error code 1, instructing the remediation script to kick off.
#> 

function Check-WindowsFirewallLogFile() {
    param([string]$fileName)
    $requiredIdentities = "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM","BUILTIN\Administrators","BUILTIN\Network Configuration Operators","NT SERVICE\MpsSvc"
    $Acl = Get-Acl $fileName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if (-NOT[string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Acl)) {
        foreach ($identity in $requiredIdentities) {
            if ($identity -notin $Acl.Access.IdentityReference.Value) {
                $needsRemediation = $true
            }
            else {
                $needsRemediation = $false
            }        
        }
        if ($needsRemediation -eq $true) {
            Write-Output "[Not good]. Acl on log file: $fileName is not properly configured. Needs remediation"
        }
        elseif ($needsRemediation -eq $false) {
            Write-Output "[All good]. Acl on log file: $fileName is properly configured. Doing nothing"
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Output "[Not good]. Log file: $fileName does not seem to exist. Needs remediation"
    }
}
try {
    $domainfw = Check-WindowsFirewallLogFile -fileName "C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\Firewall\domainfw.log"
    $privatefw = Check-WindowsFirewallLogFile -fileName "C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\Firewall\privatefw.log"
    $publicfw = Check-WindowsFirewallLogFile -fileName "C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\Firewall\publicfw.log"
    if ($domainfw.StartsWith("[Not good]") -OR $privatefw.StartsWith("[Not good]") -OR $publicfw.StartsWith("[Not good]")) {
        if ($domainfw.StartsWith("[Not good]") -eq $true) {
            Write-Output $domainfw
            exit 1
        }
        if ($privatefw.StartsWith("[Not good]") -eq $true) {
            Write-Output $privatefw
            exit 1
        }
        if ($publicfw.StartsWith("[Not good]") -eq $true) {
            Write-Output $publicfw
            exit 1
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Output "[All good]. The detection script ran successfully without errors. Doing nothing"
        exit 0
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Output "[Not good]. Something went horribly wrong when running the detection script. Please investigate"
    exit 1
}

Remediation Script:
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    This script kicks off, if the Detect-WindowsFirewallLogFiles.ps1 is exiting with error code 1.
    This script will create the log files for each firewall profile if they do not exist. If the log files are not configured the correct permissions, the script will recreate them with the proper permissions.
#> 

function New-WindowsFirewallLogFile() {
    param([string]$fileName)
    New-Item $FileName -Type File -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $Acl = Get-Acl $FileName
    $Acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True,$False)
    $PermittedUsers = @('NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM','BUILTIN\Administrators','BUILTIN\Network Configuration Operators','NT SERVICE\MpsSvc')
    foreach ($PermittedUser in $PermittedUsers) {
        $Permission = $PermittedUser,'FullControl','Allow'
        $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $Permission
        $Acl.AddAccessRule($AccessRule)
    }
    $Acl.SetOwner((New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount('BUILTIN\Administrators')))
    $Acl | Set-Acl $FileName 
}
try {
    New-WindowsFirewallLogFile -fileName "C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\firewall\domainfw.log"
    New-WindowsFirewallLogFile -fileName 'C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\firewall\domainfw.log.old'
    New-WindowsFirewallLogFile -fileName 'C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\firewall\privatefw.log'
    New-WindowsFirewallLogFile -fileName 'C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\firewall\privatefw.log.old'
    New-WindowsFirewallLogFile -fileName 'C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\firewall\publicfw.log'
    New-WindowsFirewallLogFile -fileName 'C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\firewall\publicfw.log.old'
    Write-Output "[All good]. Remediation script is done running"
    exit 0
}
catch {
    Write-Output "[Not good]. Something went horribly wrong when running the remediation script. Please investigate"
    exit 1
}

Then there's the two scripts for the logging files and their size, I then need to combine these two, they are as follows:
Detection Script:
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    This script detects if each firewall profile is configured to enable logging.
    If any of the 3 profiles is not configured accordingly, the script will exit with error code 1, instructing the remediation script to kick off.
#> 

function Get-WindowsFirewallLogging() {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [ValidateSet("Domain","Private","Public")]
        [string]$profileName,
        [string]$logFileName,
        [string]$logSize,
        [ValidateSet("True","False")]
        [string]$logAllowed,
        [ValidateSet("True","False")]
        [string]$logBlocked
    )
    $currentProfile = Get-NetFirewallProfile -Name $profileName
    if ($currentProfile.LogFileName -ne $logFileName) {
        Write-Output "[Not good]. $($currentProfile.LogFileName) is not equal to logFileName: $logFileName. Needs remediation"
        $global:needsRemediation = $true
    }
    if ($currentProfile.LogMaxSizeKilobytes -ne $logSize) {
        Write-Output "[Not good]. $($currentProfile.LogMaxSizeKilobytes) is not equal to logSize: $logSize. Needs remediation"
        $global:needsRemediation = $true
    }
    if ($currentProfile.LogAllowed -ne $logAllowed) {
        Write-Output "[Not good]. $($currentProfile.LogAllowed) is not equal to logAllowed: $logAllowed. Needs remediation"
        $global:needsRemediation = $true
    }
    if ($currentProfile.LogBlocked -ne $logBlocked) {
        Write-Output "[Not good]. $($currentProfile.LogBlocked) is not equal to logBlocked: $logBlocked. Needs remediation"
        $global:needsRemediation = $true
    }
}
try {
    Clear-Variable -Name needsRemediation -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $domainfw = Get-WindowsFirewallLogging -profileName Domain -logFileName C:\Windows\system32\logfiles\firewall\domainfw.log -logSize 32767 -logAllowed True -logBlocked True
    $privatefw = Get-WindowsFirewallLogging -profileName Private -logFileName C:\Windows\system32\logfiles\firewall\privatefw.log -logSize 32767 -logAllowed True -logBlocked True
    $publicfw = Get-WindowsFirewallLogging -profileName Public -logFileName C:\Windows\system32\logfiles\firewall\publicfw.log -logSize 32767 -logAllowed True -logBlocked True
    if ($global:needsRemediation -eq $true) {
        if (($domainfw -ne $null) -OR ($privatefw -ne $null) -OR ($publicfw -ne $null)) {
            if ($domainfw -ne $null) {
                Write-Output $domainfw
                exit 1
            }
            if ($privatefw -ne $null) {
                Write-Output $privatefw
                exit 1
            }
            if ($publicfw -ne $null) {
                Write-Output $publicfw
                exit 1
            }       
        }   
    }
    else {
        Write-Output "[All good]. The detection script ran successfully without errors. Doing nothing"
        exit 0
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Output "[Not good]. Something went horribly wrong when running the detection script. Please investigate"
    exit 1
}

Remediation Script
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    This script will configure logging for all 3 firewall profiles.
    The logging path will be set to a specific path, the log size to 32767KB and enable logging for allowed and blocked packages
#> 

function Set-WindowsFirewallLogging() {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [ValidateSet("Domain","Private","Public")]
        [string]$profileName,
        [string]$logFileName,
        [string]$logSize,
        [ValidateSet("True","False")]
        [string]$logAllowed,
        [ValidateSet("True","False")]
        [string]$logBlocked
    )
    $currentProfile = Get-NetFirewallProfile -Name $profileName
    if ($currentProfile.LogFileName -ne $logFileName) {
        Set-NetFirewallProfile -Name $profileName -LogFileName $logFileName
    }
    if ($currentProfile.LogMaxSizeKilobytes -ne $logSize) {
        Set-NetFirewallProfile -Name $profileName -LogMaxSizeKilobytes $logSize
    }
    if ($currentProfile.LogAllowed -ne $logAllowed) {
        Set-NetFirewallProfile -Name $profileName -LogAllowed $logAllowed
    }
    if ($currentProfile.LogBlocked -ne $logBlocked) {
        Set-NetFirewallProfile -Name $profileName -LogBlocked $logBlocked
    }
}
try {
    Set-WindowsFirewallLogging -profileName Domain -logFileName C:\Windows\system32\logfiles\firewall\domainfw.log -logSize 32767 -logAllowed True -logBlocked True
    Set-WindowsFirewallLogging -profileName Private -logFileName C:\Windows\system32\logfiles\firewall\privatefw.log -logSize 32767 -logAllowed True -logBlocked True
    Set-WindowsFirewallLogging -profileName Public -logFileName C:\Windows\system32\logfiles\firewall\publicfw.log -logSize 32767 -logAllowed True -logBlocked True
    Write-Output "[All good]. Remediation script is done running"
    exit 0
}
catch {
    Write-Output "[Not good]. Something went horribly wrong when running the remediation script. Please investigate"
    exit 1
}

Could anyone help me with this please? It would be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks,
A

Please provide an MRE ([mre]) and describe the problem. With no MRE, the question my attract downvotes and votes to close.

@lit I've edited it, hopefully it's clearer now and someone can help?

Anyone have any input on this? Thanks

What problems are you having in putting these scripts together? If there are error messages, please copy/paste them into the question as text. No pictures.

@lit It's more I'm struggling to compile it to run as a one time script as opposed to it being laid out for remediations. I can try and run the scripts together and remove the exit commands. I will let you know the results of this.
